# sp_sequence_get_range equivalent in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sequence

Do we have sp_sequence_get_range equivalent in Oracle.

I need to advance my sequence by some numbers always how can I achieve this.

Comment: What does `sp_sequence_get_range` do?

Answer (score 1):

Just alter then increment the sequence.

For example, to increment by 1000:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE yoursequence INCREMENT BY 1000;
```

You then have to `SELECT` the `NEXTVAL` from the sequence and re-alter it to increment by the usual value to restore "normal" operation.

To check the current value without incrementing:

```
SELECT yoursequence.CURRVAL FROM DUAL;
```

If you need to decrease the sequence, just `ALTER SEQUENCE` by a negative amount (very intuitive!).

Comment: This way when I choose next value from my sequence it is always come by 1000 delta or increment value which I didn't want

Comment: Edited. This is equivalent to marking a number of sequences as used, which is what sp_sequence_get_range appears to do.

Comment: sp_sequence_get_range it just provide you a range of number without altering ddl and without altering it's INCREMENT BY value, by using this it will ALTER INCREMENT BY value too

Comment: Not possible in Oracle. You have to do what I suggest above, you've no choice but to use DDL.

Comment: Ok, one more question is like in multi-user environment will it work fine. I mean I am afraid what if there are lots of user accessing this system simultaneously, I believe these are chances that it will give some wrong value. What is the locking mechanism can I lock this whole procedure in Oracle like we do in SQL sp_get_applock

Answer (score 0):

since the Procedure structure in `MSSQL`  is:

```
EXEC sys.sp_sequence_get_range
    @sequence_name     = ‘CyclingSequence’,
    @range_size        = 3,
    @range_first_value = @firstValue OUTPUT,
    @range_last_value  = @lastValue OUTPUT;
SELECT
    FirstValue = CONVERT(INT, @firstValue),
    LastVlaue = CONVERT(INT, @lastValue),
    NextValue = NEXT VALUE FOR CyclingSequence
GO
```

Then we can convert it to:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name
  MINVALUE value
  MAXVALUE value
  START WITH value
  INCREMENT BY value;
```

Or you can  make ORACLE function for example (I don't claim ownership of the function):

```
declare
  v_initial number := 1;
  temp      number := 0;
  cmd       varchar2(100);

begin
  cmd := 'alter sequence SEQ increment by -1';
  execute immediate cmd;

  while true loop
    cmd := 'select SEQ.nextval from dual';
    execute immediate cmd;

    select last_number
      into temp
      from user_sequences
     where sequence_name = 'SEQ';

    if temp = v_initial then
       exit;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: What does *"(I don't claim ownership of the function)"* mean? Did you copy this from somewhere else? if yes, please add proper attribution.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I have some notes to keep any issue that takes a lot of time for me to solve. I cant recall what is the source URL.